# compiler errors, I do not underdstand

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I want to make it work to where I run ComplexTest.class and then in that class it runs Complex.class. I'm pretty new at java I have no idea what's wrong. Not sure why the compiler expects to see .class and a semi colon where it thinks they should be.

Main class

```
public class ComplexTest 
{
    //private final double re;   // the real part
    //private final double im;   // the imaginary part
        public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
    {
        CreateObjs();
        PrintHeader1();
        PrintHeader2();
        // invoke and Initialize a Complex object
             Complex Comp = new Complex(); // Invokes Complex constructor (pg 315)
             Comp.JunctionBox(CompA, CompB);
            // multiply.printQuestionResult();
        }  

    public static void CreateObjs()
    {
        Complex CompA = new Complex(9.5D, 7.7D);
            Complex CompB = new Complex(1.2D, 3.1D);
    }
    public static void PrintHeader1()
    {
        System.out.printf(" A complex number in the \n form (x, y) is equal to \n x + yi, where i is \n square root of -1.\n");
    }
    public static void PrintHeader2()
    {
        System.out.printf("\n *-Complex numbers calculations-*");
    }
}
```

2nd class

```
/******************************************************************************
 *  Data type for complex numbers.
 *
 *  The data type is "imagmutable" so once you create and initialize
 *  a Complex object, you cannot change it. The "final" keyword
 *  when declaring re and imag enforces this rule, making it a
 *  compile-timage error to change the .re or .imag fields after
 *  they've been initialized.
 *
 *  % java Complex
 *  a            = 5.0 + 6.0i
 *  b            = -3.0 + 4.0i
 *  b + a        = 2.0 + 10.0i
 *  a - b        = 8.0 + 2.0i
 *  a * b        = -39.0 + 2.0i
 *  a / b        = 0.36 - 1.52i
******************************************************************************/
public class Complex {
    // Constants (final)
    private final double re;   // the real part
    private final double imag;   // the imaginaryinary part
    // Variables
    public double product;

    // create a new object with the given real and imaginaryinary parts
    public Complex(double real, double imaginary) {
        re = real;
        imag = imaginary;
    }

    // return a string representation of the invoking Complex object
    public String toString() {
        if (imag == 0) return "<" + re + ">";
        if (re == 0) return "<" + imag + ">";
        if (imag <  0) return "<" + re + " - " + (-imag) + ">";
        return "<" + re + ", " + imag + ">";// + "i";
    }

    // return a new Complex object whose value is (this + b)
    public Complex plus(Complex b) {
        Complex a = this;             // invoking object
        double real = a.re + b.re;
        double imaginary = a.imag + b.imag;
        return new Complex(real, imaginary);
    }

    // return a new Complex object whose value is (this - b)
    public Complex minus(Complex b) {
        Complex a = this;
        double real = a.re - b.re;
        double imaginary = a.imag - b.imag;
        return new Complex(real, imaginary);
    }

    // return a new Complex object whose value is (this * b)
    public Complex timages(Complex b) {
        Complex a = this;
        double real = a.re * b.re - a.imag * b.imag;
        double imaginary = a.re * b.imag + a.imag * b.re;
        return new Complex(real, imaginary);
    }

    // return a new Complex object whose value is the reciprocal of this
    public Complex reciprocal() {
        double scale = re*re + imag*imag;
        return new Complex(re / scale, -imag / scale);
    }

    // return the real or imaginaryinary part
    public double re() { return re; }
    public double imag() { return imag; }

    // return a / b
    public Complex divides(Complex b) {
        Complex a = this;
        return a.timages(b.reciprocal());
    }

    // sample client for testing
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex a = new Complex(9.5, 7.7);
        Complex b = new Complex(1.2, 3.1);

        System.out.printf("a            = %s\n", a);
        System.out.println("b            = " + b);
        System.out.println("a + b        = " + a.plus(b));
        System.out.println("a - b        = " + a.minus(b));
        System.out.println("a * b        = " + a.timages(b));
        System.out.println("a / b        = " + a.divides(b));
    }
}
```

Compiler/Syntax errors:

```
ComplexTest.java:15: error: constructor Complex in class Complex cannot be applied to given types;
                 Complex Comp = new Complex(); // Invokes Complex constructor (pg 315)
                                ^
  required: double,double
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
ComplexTest.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                 Comp.JunctionBox(CompA, CompB);
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable CompA
  location: class ComplexTest
ComplexTest.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                 Comp.JunctionBox(CompA, CompB);
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable CompB
  location: class ComplexTest
3 errors
```

EDIT1: Fixed the junk class, updated the errors code block. I knew that the junk class was a problem.

EDIT2: I need more help, I am making more errors trying to fix the ones I already have.

Comment: Remove that JunctionBox class.

Comment: 1.) Complex.class needs a no-argument constructor
2.) main() cannot see what you've created in CreateObj(), it's out of scope.  So, get rid of CreateObjs() and construct CompA & CompB directly within main()

Comment: The answer should go in the answer section

Comment: @DebosmitRay what do you mean by that?

Comment: @GeekyDewd You have updated the original errors in the post with corrected code. The original post should be left with the error and any changes made to correct it should be put in the answer section.

Comment: @DebosmitRayFeel free to edit. Literally all I did was remove the unused class JunctionBox, and update the error list after doing after doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "junk" class declaration messing the file up.

```
public class JunctionBox() {

}
```

...is not a valid class declaration to begin with (the brackets should not be there), and you should only have a single public class declaration - with the class named as the file - in each Java file.

Removing that class declaration would make the file compile correctly.

Comment: Removed the unnecessary class (shouldn't have even been a class but a function)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to having the concatenation of double and string you have to convert them first to string in every way possible
for example in the following way

change 

 `if (imag == 0) return "<" + re + ">"`

to

 `if (imag == 0) return "<" + String.valueOf(re) + ">"`

Answer (score 0):

Some errors are: 
1) in the main method of ComplexTest you invoke the empty Constructor Complex() that you have not defined yet.
2) in the next line of code you use CompA and CompB object, but you have not defined them.
3) In the second file you first declare JunctionBox Class, but you put a main method method in a secodary class of the same file.
Correct first the above errors and the update you question.

Comment: For #1 I made another program where Multiply3Test looks like:
>public class Multiply3Test {
>
>    public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString){
>        //invoke and Initialize a Multiply3 object
>        Multiply3 multiply = new Multiply3(); // Invokes Multiply3 >constructor (pg 315)
>        multiply.quiz();
>        multiply.printQuestionResult();
>    }
>    
>}

Comment: somebody freakin format this for me, website stinks